# cannot get correct response after upgrade to react-native 0.44

Tags: ios, react-native

previously I use axios launch XHR when rely on react-native@0.42 on iOS platform, it works well.
But now I encounter following issue after I migrate project to react-native@0.44

version info:

- react-native: 0.44
- react: 16.0.0-alpha.6
- axios: 0.16.1

error info:

[image]

I can't understand why it throw suddenly, how should I fix it?

thanks for your time,

regards.